# How to append elements from 2 short lists into another big list of tuples?

Tags: python, list, tuples

Say I have the following lists:

```
l1 = [('a','b','c'),('d','e','f'),('g','h','i'),('j','k','l')]
l2 = ['x','y','z']
l3 = ['m','n']
```

I want to extract elements from l2 and l3, then append l2[i](`i in range(len(l2))`) as the first element inside every tuple, and l3[i](`i in range(len(l2))`) as the last element inside every tuple.

so the result will look like the followings:

```
l1 = [('x','a','b','c','m'),('x','a','b','c','n'),('y','a','b','c','m'),('y','a','b','c','n'), ('z','a','b','c','m'),('z','a','b','c','n')]
```

and yes, the len of l1 will be increased.

Comment: So you don't care about anything but the first tuple in `l1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with the help of [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) and [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), and get the cartesian product, like this

```
>>> from itertools import chain, product
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint([tuple(chain.from_iterable(i)) for i in product(l2, [l1[0]], l3)])
[('x', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'm'),
 ('x', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'n'),
 ('y', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'm'),
 ('y', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'n'),
 ('z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'm'),
 ('z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'n')]
```

You are finding the cartesian product between `l2`, the first element of `l1` and `l3`. Since the result will be a tuple with the element from `l2` (a string) and the first element of `l1` (a tuple) and an element from `l3` (a string), we flatten it with `chain.from_iterable`.

Let's say we don't flatten the tuples, then this is what you will get

```
>>> pprint([tuple(items) for items in product(l2, [l1[0]], l3)])
[('x', ('a', 'b', 'c'), 'm'),
 ('x', ('a', 'b', 'c'), 'n'),
 ('y', ('a', 'b', 'c'), 'm'),
 ('y', ('a', 'b', 'c'), 'n'),
 ('z', ('a', 'b', 'c'), 'm'),
 ('z', ('a', 'b', 'c'), 'n')]
```

This is why we use `chain.from_iterable` and flatten the tuples.

Answer (score 1):

What about playing with `zip` and list comprehension :

```
>>> [zip(*i) for i in zip(zip(l2,l2),zip(l1,l1),(l3 for _ in range(2*len(l1))))]
[[('x', ('a', 'b', 'c'), 'm'), ('x', ('a', 'b', 'c'), 'n')], [('y', ('d', 'e', 'f'), 'm'), ('y', ('d', 'e', 'f'), 'n')], [('z', ('g', 'h', 'i'), 'm'), ('z', ('g', 'h', 'i'), 'n')]]
```